# Case style of tables and field (Naming Conventions)

Tags: naming-convention

What is best practice for naming dbs, tables (collections) and fields among DBMSs?

I mean casing style, for example `AaaBaa`,`aaa-bbb`, `aaa_bbb`, `AAA-BBB`, `aaaBbb`, ...

I think if one exists it should be applicable to all DBMSs  (MySQL, MongoDB, Oracle, ...), shouldn't it?

Currently I thing following is most appropriate:

Columns/Fields/Tables/Collections/Databases:  `aaaBbbCcc`.

Could distinct case style for these object be useful at all?

Comment: In my opinion, there can be no *objectively* best practice with regard to object naming. Conventions, company policies, yes, a universally best choice, no.

Comment: There *might* be a general agreement on what to *avoid* using, though (like e.g. `aAAAbBBB`, perhaps).

Answer (score 1):

It all boils down to **personal preference** and **consistency** within your team (or just yourself). Nothing worse than seeing different styles mixed.

As for SQL Server, be mindful of sp_yourProcName, as "sp_" prefix for a stored procedure can do funny things ([read more about this from Aaron Bertrand](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix)).

*Consistency is king. Make your choice and stick with it.*

Answer (score 0):

The SQL standard mandates that names are case-insensitive (specifically, that any lower-case letter in a name should compare equal to the corresponding upper-case letter).

For this reason, a table name with *mixed* case is a poor idea: the names `ExpertsExchange` is mandated to be equal to the name `EXPERTSEXCHANGE`. Letter case cannot distinguish those names in a conformant DBMS.

So, if you want to separate words in a name, *don't use letter case*. Instead, use the underscore (`_`) to separate words.

And, if you don't want your names to be shouty, spell them in all lower case.

For these reasons I recommend `lower_case_with_underscore` names.